# how to set url with 'send the server' button in ckeditor ? primefaces

Tags: jsf, ckeditor, primefaces-extensions

I upload image to db in ckeditor.with below config:

```
    CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function(config) {
      var contextPath= $(.contextPath).html();
      config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl =contextPath+ '/ckeditor/getimage';
      config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = contextPath+'ckeditor/uploadimage';
      config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = contextPath+'/ckeditor/getimage';
   };
```

I use this servlet for upload to db.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public class CKEditorUploadServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7570633768412575697L;

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(CKEditorUploadServlet.class);
    private static final String ERROR_FILE_UPLOAD = "An error occurred to the file upload process.";
    private static final String ERROR_NO_FILE_UPLOAD = "No file is present for upload process.";
    private static final String ERROR_INVALID_CALLBACK = "Invalid callback.";
    private static final String CKEDITOR_CONTENT_TYPE = "text/html; charset=UTF-8";
    private static final String CKEDITOR_HEADER_NAME = "Cache-Control";
    private static final String CKEDITOR_HEADER_VALUE = "no-cache";

    private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("[\\w\\d]*");

    private String errorMessage = "";

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        LOG.info("doGet çalışmaya başladı.");
        doPost(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        LOG.info("doPost çalışmaya başladı.");
        final ApplicationContext ctx = WebApplicationContextUtils
                .getWebApplicationContext(request.getSession()
                        .getServletContext());
        final UploadedFileService uploadedFileService = (UploadedFileService) ctx
                .getBean("UploadedFileService");

        final UploadedFile uploadedFile = new UploadedFile();
        final PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        response.setContentType(CKEDITOR_CONTENT_TYPE);
        response.setHeader(CKEDITOR_HEADER_NAME, CKEDITOR_HEADER_VALUE);

        final FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
        final ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

        try {
            final List items = upload.parseRequest(request);
            if (!items.isEmpty() && items.get(0) != null) {
                uploadedFile.setContent(((DiskFileItem) items.get(0)).get());
                uploadedFile.setContentType(((DiskFileItem) items.get(0))
                        .getContentType());
                uploadedFile.setName(((DiskFileItem) items.get(0)).getName());
                uploadedFileService.saveUploadedFile(uploadedFile);
            } else {
                errorMessage = ERROR_NO_FILE_UPLOAD;
            }

        } catch (final FileUploadException e) {
            errorMessage = ERROR_FILE_UPLOAD;
            LOG.error(errorMessage, e);
        }

        // CKEditorFuncNum Is the location to display when the callback
        String callback = request.getParameter("CKEditorFuncNum");
        // verify if the callback contains only digits and letters in order to
        // avoid vulnerability on parsing parameter
        if (!PATTERN.matcher(callback).matches()) {
            callback = "";
            errorMessage = ERROR_INVALID_CALLBACK;
        }
        final String pathToFile = request.getContextPath()
                + "/ckeditor/getimage?imageId=" + uploadedFile.getId();
        out.println("<script type='text/javascript'>// <![CDATA[window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction("
                + callback + ",'" + pathToFile + "','" + errorMessage + "')");
        out.println("// ]]></script>");
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }
}
```

and I use this servlet for get and view image from db.

```
public class CKEditorGetImageServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -7570633768412575697L;

private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory
        .getLogger(CKEditorGetImageServlet.class);
private static final String ERROR_FILE_DOWNLOAD = "An error occured when trying to get the image with id:";
private static final String IMAGE_PARAMETER_NAME = "imageId";
private static final long CACHE_AGE_MILISECONDS_TWO_WEEKS = 1209600000;
private static final String CKEDITOR_CONTENT_EXPIRE = "Expires";
private static final String CKEDITOR_CONTENT_TYPE = "Content-Type";
private static final String CKEDITOR_CONTENT_LENGTH = "Content-Length";
private static final String CKEDITOR_CONTENT_DISPOSITION = "Content-Disposition";
private static final String CKEDITOR_CONTENT_DISPOSITION_VALUE = "inline; filename=\"";
private static final String CKEDITOR_HEADER_NAME = "Cache-Control";

@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    Long imageId = null;
    final ApplicationContext ctx = WebApplicationContextUtils
            .getWebApplicationContext(request.getSession()
                    .getServletContext());
    final UploadedFileService uploadedFileService = (UploadedFileService) ctx
            .getBean("UploadedFileService");
    final String parameterId = request.getParameter(IMAGE_PARAMETER_NAME);

    try {
        imageId = Long.valueOf(parameterId);
        final UploadedFile uploadedFile = uploadedFileService
                .getUploadedFileById(imageId);
        if (uploadedFile != null && uploadedFile.getContent().length > 0) {
            final byte[] rb = uploadedFile.getContent();
            final long expiry = new Date().getTime()
                    + CACHE_AGE_MILISECONDS_TWO_WEEKS;
            response.setDateHeader(CKEDITOR_CONTENT_EXPIRE, expiry);
            response.setHeader(CKEDITOR_HEADER_NAME, "max-age="
                    + CACHE_AGE_MILISECONDS_TWO_WEEKS);
            response.setHeader(CKEDITOR_CONTENT_TYPE,
                    uploadedFile.getContentType());
            response.setHeader(CKEDITOR_CONTENT_LENGTH,
                    String.valueOf(rb.length));
            response.setHeader(
                    CKEDITOR_CONTENT_DISPOSITION,
                    CKEDITOR_CONTENT_DISPOSITION_VALUE
                            + uploadedFile.getName() + "\"");
            response.getOutputStream().write(rb, 0, rb.length);
            response.getOutputStream().flush();
            response.getOutputStream().close();
        }
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        response.getOutputStream().close();
        LOG.error(ERROR_FILE_DOWNLOAD + parameterId, e);
    }
}
```

}

I upload with ckeditor image to db.OK.But when I click the 'image info' tab,I should write manually /(contextPath)/ckeditor/getimage?imageId=(image id in the db)(example.when the write this url:/contextPath/ckeditor/getimage?imageId=1 to url's input in image info tab,all is ok.But I want to write to url automatically when the send the server your custom image.How can I do that? manual is not useful for users.How can I set to url(image info tab) automatically?Thanks in advance..
I use primefaces-extensions ckeditor.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little late, but this worked for me... in ckeditor 4.4.6, PF 5.2, PFE 3.2.0:

```
private static final String ERROR_INVALID_CALLBACK = "Invalid callback.";
private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("[\\w\\d]*");

    // CKEditorFuncNum Is the location to display when the callback
    String callback = request.getParameter("CKEditorFuncNum");
    // verify if the callback contains only digits and letters in order to
    // avoid vulnerability on parsing parameter
    if (!PATTERN.matcher(callback).matches()) {
        callback = "";
        errorMessage = ERROR_INVALID_CALLBACK;
    }
    String pathToFile = request.getContextPath() + "/ckeditor/getimage?imageId=" + uploadedFile.getId();
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">//<![CDATA[" + "\n\twindow.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(" + callback + ",'" + pathToFile + "','" + errorMessage + "')");
    out.println("//]]></script>");
    out.flush();
    out.close();
```